# Is the binomial distribution appropriate?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Say there's a group of *p* monkeys.

Some of the monkeys, a total of *yp* (where 0<*y*<1), each has an amount *x* of banana-cake to give away, which they will distribute generously to the whole rest of the group. Each one does this by dividing the *x* banana-cake into *n* slices, and chucking each slice at random into the group of all other monkeys. Each does this *n* times, until all their *x* banana-cake has been distributed. (Some lucky monkeys might receive several slices of cake.) Once all the banana-cake has been distributed, the monkeys all sit around happily until, tragically, a total *dp* of the monkeys (where 0<*d*<1) is brutally slaughtered by a horde of marauding hippopotamuses.

I'd be interested to know what the expected distribution of monkeys with different amounts of banana-cake is after all this has taken place. How many monkeys have, say, *x* bits of banana-cake, how many have *x/2*, etc.

I believe I'd need to use the binomial distribution, but am not quite sure how. Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Just a question, do the monkeys, in spite of their mourning, take the delicious banana-cake from their passed loved ones and redistribute the cake?

Comment: Sadly not. (I suspect the hippos make off with it.)

Comment: A plain binomial distribution will not work because our generous monkeys are described so altruistically that they would never take a slice of their own cake... Oh and WTF did I just read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but a comment can't be properly made to display block code, so here's a little MATLAB script to murder thousands of innocent (virtual) monkeys and look at the distribution, you monster:

```
function stats = q1427076(N, monkeys, cakes, kills, slices)
    stats = zeros(cakes * slices - 1, 1);
    for i=1:N
        x = zeros(monkeys,1);
        for c=1:cakes
            m = randi(monkeys-1,slices,1); % we won't take a slice of our own cake, will we?
            m(m >= c) = m(m >= c) + 1;
            x(m) = x(m) + 1; % Give it to a buddy
        end
        for k=1:kills
            x(randi(length(x))) = []; % You monster.
        end
        for s=1:length(x)
            stats(x(s) + 1) = stats(x(s) + 1) + 1; % Keep the record
        end
    end
    stats = stats / N / (monkeys-kills); % Make it a PDF
end
```

Where $\text{monkeys} = p$, $\text{cakes} = yp$, $\text{kills} = dp$ and $\text{slices} = n$. $N$ is the number of times to conduct the experiment. Bigger is better but slower.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Clicked the tick as my own next step was to do it in Matlab. What it must be to have brains.